# Multiple keyspace or table update for cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, batch-processing, datastax, nosql

Is it a good idea to send batch update statements spanning multiple table? Will it generate a heavier workload on the coordination node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is a bad idea to send **LOGGED** BATCH spanning multiple partition because it can overload the coordinator.

If you need to optimize the network and don't care about batching guarantee (that all mutation will be eventually applied) user **UNLOGGED** BATCH

Comment: Thanks for answering. For unlogged batch, do we always need to have **date** as part of the _partition_ key?

Comment: Having a **date** as part of *partition key* is all about data model. And batching and data model are **unrelated**